# Exception with null message

Tags: c#, exception

I found that exception message can't be null in C#, and after trying this

```
 var ex = new Exception(null);
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```

I get the following message:

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

But, in this case,

```
 var ex = new Exception(string.Empty);
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```

the message is just empty.

How this can be explained? Do you think this is expected behavior?

Comment: Check out the ctor of `Exception` with .NET Reflector or Telerik JustDecompile :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers (not including the answer from chopikadze) seem to be based on a misreading of the facts.  Neither example is throwing an exception.

Rather, in the first example, the constructed exception `ex` is providing a message because the value of the constructor's message parameter was null.  The message is "an exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown".

It's a fairly common practice to have some fallback behavior when an object reference is null, so that's "how it can be explained".  Whether it is "expected", of course, depends on your expectations.

Throwing exceptions in the course of handling exceptions can be problematic, so the framework designers must have chosen this behavior to reduce this possibility.  It would have been a nightmare, frankly, if we all had to cover the possibility that exception messages might be null.

**EDIT**

The behavior is also documented in [the remarks for the Message property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx): "If no message was supplied to the constructor for the current instance, the system supplies a default message that is formatted using the current system culture."

I looked in the CLI spec and in the C# spec, and I found no mention of a requirement that Message have a non-null return value, so I guess that supports the view that this behavior is a framework design decision.

Comment: I tried to change "test" code to: var ex = new NotSupportedException(null); After this message is changed to "Exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' was thrown." So it looks like this behaviors isn't used for showing that you pass null to Exception's constructor.

Comment: The message will show the actual type of the exception.  See edited answer for more detail, and chopikadze's answer for the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually constructor doesn't need string, you can absolutely surely use null. This is reflectored part of Exception class:

```
internal string _message;

public Exception(string message)
{
    this.Init();
    this._message = message;
}


private void Init()
{
    this._message = null;
    this._stackTrace = null;
    this._dynamicMethods = null;
    this.HResult = -2146233088;
    this._xcode = -532462766;
    this._xptrs = IntPtr.Zero;
    this._watsonBuckets = null;
    this._ipForWatsonBuckets = UIntPtr.Zero;
    this._safeSerializationManager = new SafeSerializationManager();
}

public virtual string Message
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        if (this._message != null)
        {
            return this._message;
        }
        if (this._className == null)
        {
            this._className = this.GetClassName();
        }
        return Environment.GetRuntimeResourceString("Exception_WasThrown", new object[] { this._className });
    }
}
```

So if you use null as message in constructor, localized string like "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown." will be used as Message. It means - there is still your Exception, not another one, but it's property Message returns another (calculated) value instead of null from constructor.

I think that it's defined by design (and maybe is used in another places) that Exception.Message should be always not null. So if we want to allow developers use default constructor for Exception class (for example, for using with reflection or for allowing to populate properties later) but we also want to has Message always not null - we should wrap Message with something. I think, one of the possible place of Message usage is default dialog box showed after exception occurs. This way there could be used just Message property, instead of checking - is Message property equals to null etc.

Comment: Old stuff, but Exception.Message may well be null in practice. Try 
throw new System.Web.UI.ViewStateException(); for example.

Answer (score 2):

`string.Empty` is not null it is a constant for `""`.

Your first example is giving a default message, your second example is an empty string

Comment: The first example is *not* producing a null reference exception; the constructed exception `ex` is providing a message because the message parameter was null, so the call to `ex.Message` is returning the string "an exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown".

Comment: yeah which is wrapping a null reference, because he is trying to write a null string to the console....

Comment: Console.WriteLine((string)null); doesn't throw Exception. There is no new exception, Message property just returns another string instead of null

Comment: no @Maess, it assign "an exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown" to Message, which is not expected

Comment: @Maess no: If there were a null reference, the code would be throwing a NullReferenceException.  That's not happening.  Rather, the message "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown." is being written to the console.  I did not downvote your answer, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the constructor you are using requires a string. String.Empty is not the same as null therefore it will throw an exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx

Comment: It will not throw an Exception. Create project for console application, copy/paste code, and use debugger. There is no exceptions!

Comment: As said, it doesn't throw exception it assign that string tom Message